# как провести путь к переменной в kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

помогите пожалуйста провести путь к переменой text_1 из  MDLabel.text.
Постарался понятно объяснить.Использовался в коде kivyMD

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


KV = '''




Screen:

    NavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            Screen:
                name: "screen 1"

                BoxLayout
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        id: toolbar
                        title: "хз"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: x]]

                    Carousel:
                        id: carousel

                        Screen:

                            MDLabel:
                                text: "спс"
                                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .97}
                                halign: "center"

                            MDLabel:
                                id : text_sreen1
                                text:"присвоить значение из перемной "       


                                anchor_x: "left"
                                size_hint_y: None
                                pos_hint: {"center_y": .8, "center_x": .51}    







'''




class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)


    def text_up(self):
        text_1 = self.root.ids.text_screen1.text = \
        '''
        присвоить значение тексту
        '''



class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PY:

```
def text_up(self):
    text_1 = \
    '''
    присвоить значение тексту
    '''
    return text_1
```

KV:

```
                        MDLabel:
                            id : text_sreen1
                            text: app.text_up()
```

Comment: а если у меня будет куча таких текстов, мне для каждой отдельную новую  функцию вызывать ?